# remove line space in WordPress post to remove links from images

Tags: wordpress

I want to remove line space between anchor and img tag, So I can disable link of image.

**I have followed below code :-**

```
 function attachment_image_link_remove_filter( $content ) {
   $content =
    preg_replace(array('{<a[^>]*><img}','{/></a>}'),array('<img','/>'), $content);
    return $content;
 }
```

**Here is sample code That I want to fix :-**

```
<a href="link_url" rel="attachment wp-att-570">
 <img class="image_url" width="500" height="424">
</a>
```

Comment: Why do you want to do this? Did you try minify HTML instead?

Comment: With the above function it work for non line space image. Like below code
<a href="link_url" rel="attachment wp-att-570"> <img class="image_url" width="500" height="424"></a>

Comment: Is there any regular expression to do this ?

Comment: Let's try this: `<a[^>]*>(?:\n)(.*)<img`

Comment: Its not working